# ValueError on a recursion but not in the the beginning:

Tags: python, pandas

I get the following error on the code below.

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
def calculatepct(gems,pct):

if pct < 0:        

    pct = 0

    not_in_dictionary = True        

    for child in acap1051.itertuples():

        if child.gems == gems:

            not_in_dictionary = False

            if child.parent_gems_ in all_children['gems'].values:

                mask1 = all_children[all_children["gems"] == child.parent_gems_]

                if all_children.loc[mask1.index.item()]['calculated'] == -1:

                    calculatepct(child.parent_gems_,all_children.loc[mask1.index.item()]['calculated'])
```

The code works for two cycles, but then I get a value error after this line:

```
mask1 = all_children[all_children["gems"] == child.parent_gems_]
```

Comment: can you add the full stack trace?

Comment: What is a full stack trace?  Sorry, I am new at this.

Comment: the issue can be that your mask is coming as empty and thus `mask1.index.item()` is returning an empty nparray. can you try adding output of mask across iterations to the post?